# Нужны ли запятые в данном предложении? (10)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот, обороты-с-как

> Для такого города, как этот, бейсбол малой лиги – это чудесно.

Answer (score 5):

Запятые нужны.
*Для **такого** города, **как** этот, бейсбол малой лиги – это чудесно.*

> **ТАКОЙ (,) КАК,** *местоимение + союз*
>
> По общему правилу, обороты с союзом «как» выделяются запятыми, если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово «такой». [[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722)]